# How can i have two not arguments in an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want to check if the following value is not a digit and is not "a" or "b" but I'm met with a syntax error. It says it expect ":" after not in the second argument.

`if not char.isdigit() and not in ('a', 'b'):`

I don't know what I can try to fix this. I could nest the if statement but that leads to bad code and I know there must be some solution.

Comment: ...and *what* `not in ('a', 'b')`?

Comment: `if not char.isdigit() and char not in ('a', 'b'):`

Comment: @Samwise You know, the thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line should be:

```
if not char.isdigit() and char not in ('a', 'b'):
```

You have to declare *what* variable is not in `('a', 'b')`

Furthermore, I would take a look at how to structure questions on StackOverflow.